# save grobs made in function of loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, ggplot2, gridextra

I made this long function that ends with a grob figure (3 ggplots). However, when I use this function in a loop and try to put all the resulting grobs into one super figure, I run into problems. I obtain a figure with a lot of grobs, but it's always the same grob (the first one)!

To demonstrate my problem I made this simplified example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

data(iris)

#the function
multi.plot=function(data,heading){
  p1=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()+ggtitle(heading)
  p2=ggplot(data,aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()
  p3=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Width))+geom_point()
  grob1=arrangeGrob(p1,ncol=2)
  grob2=arrangeGrob(p3,p2,ncol=2)
  grob3=arrangeGrob(grob1,grob2)
  # grob3  / return(grob3)  / print(grob3)   => all tried but non of them helps
}

# the loop
list.grob=list()
for(i in unique(iris$Species)){
  select=iris[iris$Species==i,]
  multi.plot(data=select,heading=i)
  list.grob[[which(unique(iris$Species)==i)]]=grob3  
}

# the final figure
png(file="superplot.png")
do.call("grid.arrange", list.grob)  
dev.off()
```

So how do I make a figure with a lot of grobs using a function and a loop? Also, my title ("heading") doesn't appear as it should be.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sticking by your technique of doing this, I would proceed as:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
data(iris)
```

The function

```
multi.plot=function(data=iris, heading="virginica"){
        p1=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()+ ggtitle(heading)
        p2=ggplot(data,aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()+ ggtitle(heading)
        p3=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Width))+geom_point()+ ggtitle(heading)
        grob_all=arrangeGrob(p1, p2, p3, ncol=3)
        return(grob_all)}`

grob_test <- multi.plot()
```

The loop

```
list.grob=list()
names(list.grob) <- unique(iris$Species)`

for(i in unique(iris$Species)){
  select <- iris[iris$Species==i,]
  grob_i <- multi.plot(data=select,heading=i)
  list.grob[[i]]=grob_i
}
```

The final figure

```
png(file="superplot.png")
do.call("grid.arrange", list.grob)  
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use a `for` loop here. I mean better to do it by group of Species using `by` for example:

```
by(iris,iris$Species,
   function(select)
     multi.plot(data=select,heading=unique(select$Species)))
```

Also you should simplify you `multi.plot` function :

```
#the function
multi.plot=function(data,heading){
  p1=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()+ggtitle(heading)
  p2=ggplot(data,aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Sepal.Width))+geom_point()
  p3=ggplot(data,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Width))+geom_point()
  arrangeGrob(p1,arrangeGrob(p1,p2,ncol=2))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works great on the example. But unfortunately in my real problem, I use the for loop over columns and not over factors of a row. Is there something similar I can do?

Comment: You could reshape the data so columns are values of a factor (i.e. wide to long)